# What is the major difference between Event and EventHandler?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, gwt

The reason behind of posting this question is to understand the basic differences and use cases of the `Event` and `EvenHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

**Event:-** In computing, an event is an action or occurrence detected by the program that may be handled by the program. Typically events are handled synchronously with the program flow, that is, the program has one or more dedicated places where events are handled.

**EventHandler:-**

A function or method containing program statements that are executed in response to an event. An event handler typically is a software routine that processes actions such as keystrokes and mouse movements. With Web sites, event handlers make Web content dynamic. JavaScript is a common method of scripting event handlers for Web content.

Very basic example is you click on login button on facebook, there is corresponding event handler for click on login button which tells facebook app that user trying to login

Comment: Thanks for a clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the both **Handler and event.**

All Handlers are stored with a HandlerManager which also manages dispatching any type of event (including new ones you create yourself).

More over

Handlers  are passed an Event object with all the Event details as their only parameter **i.e Event**

Answer (score 0):

They may mean different things, depending on a specific context. A general meaning of an event is a an action or occurrence somewhere in the program; normally events are handled by the program in modules called handlers.

For example in Java you may an event triggered by the push of a button; what the program does when that button is call the code in the handler for that particular event.